# Do these equivalence classes have any special property!

Tags: measure-theory, boolean-algebra, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $\lambda$ be a measure on the interval $I=[0,1]$, and Let $\mathcal{N}$ be the family of null sets. It is known that "measure algebra $\mathcal{B}$ " is the algebra of all measurable subsets of $I$ modulo $\mathcal{N}$, the elements in $\mathcal{B}$ are equivalence classes [.] determined by $\sim$ as:

> $A\sim B $ iff $A\Delta B\in \mathcal{N}$ for every measurable sets $A,B$ in $I$
>
> The class $[B]=\{A:A \text{ is measurable }, A\sim B\}$.
>
> My question is: Is it true that these class have the property that every two classes either have  empty intersection or they are equal. If yes, it means that we do not have a subclass as $[A]\subseteq[B]$.

Please someone explain this further for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  To see this, you only need to show ~ is an equivalence relation.  This boils down to showing that if $U$ and $V$ have measure zero, then so does $U \Delta V$.

Comment: I know $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. $U$ and $V$ need not to have measure zero.

Comment: (a) The property you want the classes to have follows from ~ being an equivalence relation.  (b) In my second statement, I said **if**.